# Who is Mrs. Gerber?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, it.information-theory

This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/398024/11260) on a theorem in information theory called *Mrs. Gerber's lemma* piqued my curiosity. Who is this individual, and why the "mrs." ?  A quick Google search was not informative, although it did produce a Mr. Gerber's lemma ([arXiv:1802.05861](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05861)) -- can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I heard during an information theory course that Wyner and Ziv ideated the lemma during a stay at Mrs. Gerber's inn.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check out the original reference "A theorem on the entropy of certain binary sequences and applications - I" by Wyner and Ziv: https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1973.1055107. Footnote 2 on page one explains

> This result is known as “Mrs. Gerber’s Lemma” in honor of a certain lady whose presence was keenly felt by the authors at the time this research was done.

I'm not sure you're going to get more of an explanation than that.

Comment: hmm, Wyner and Ziv must have been asked the question, who and why, they left us no answer?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [Jacob Ziv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Ziv) is alive and active: he accepted the IEEE medal of honour this very year. I suggest writing to him and asking.

Comment: good idea, I sent an email inquiry to professor Ziv.

Comment: well, professor Ziv responded promptly: _As far as I recall, the name "Mrs. Gerber" was an insider joke shared by Aaron and myself._ -- so that is it, we won't know more & I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 13):

Aaron used to tell us (his colleagues at Bell Labs) that Jacob was renting a place from Mrs. Gerber while visiting Bell Labs and working on the lemma with Aaron. Mrs. Gerber interrupted them a few times when they worked at Jacob's home.